# Props are not passed to route.push in vue on TS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a simple application structure, table and page to create a new item, to create a new item i use the button on the main page to go to the item create page

```
initNewRow(): void {
    let someData: string = 'someText';
    this.$router.push({
        name: 'catalog-create___en',
        params: { someData: someData }
    });
}
```

I want to pass some parameters in the navigation, there is no given page in the route, because I don't need to display it in the menu

only a page with a table (there is no page for creating an element)

```
{
    id: 8,
    label: 'menuitems.Catalog.text',
    link: '/catalog/main',
    icon: 'ri-eye-line',      
    meta: {
        middleware: ['router-auth']
    }
},
```

when the page for creating an item in props opens, I don’t have it, and why I can’t understand

```
@Component({
    name: 'Create',
    props: ['someData']
})
export default class Catalog extends Vue {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    someData!: any;

    constructor() {
         super();
         this.someData = this.$route.params.someData;
         console.log(this.someData);
    }
```

How to properly initialize a property? it gives me an error right now in console log:

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "someData"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [official documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#programmatic-navigation)

Those are all the ways that can be used, the one you're using cannot work

```js
const userId = '123'
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId } }) // -> /user/123
router.push({ path: `/user/${userId}` }) // -> /user/123
// This will NOT work
router.push({ path: '/user', params: { userId } }) // -> /user
```

Update it to something like

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'create', params: { someData } });
```

Here is where to find the routes you do have in your project thanks to the Vue devtools
[image]

Comment: I understand, but what if I don't have a create name in the routing?

and in fact, I transfer data that does not belong to the url, I need it to work in the form

Comment: You do have a name generated out of the box for you. You can find it in the Vue devtools, `Routing > Routes` section. Otherwise as I told: make an interpolation as written on the 3rd line of my first snippet of code.

Comment: `and in fact, I transfer data that does not belong to the url, I need it to work in the form` I don't understand what you mean here. Please provide more details.

Comment: i don’t need these parameters in the path to my page “Create”

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров I'm answering to your question here. Are you maybe planning to send a `POST` to a backend maybe? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: i am trying to pass some parameters to a page without using url: catalog/:id

Comment: Oh yeah true, sorry! You're not trying to pass a `query` but `params`. In that case, you need to find out the route name. Check my updated answer to find out the name of your route. @ЯрославПрохоров

Comment: I changed the basic example, how to properly initialize a property?

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров this one can be easily found on Google and deserve it's whole new question but this blog post may help: https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly/ Mainly, `someData` here comes as a prop but is mutated later on. If the parent updates, this one will conflict and re-render, which is not the way to go. Computed setter is one way to fix it, as explained in the article.